# TagListView single selection swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, taglist

I try to create tag using cocoa pod of TagListView https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView.
I use TagListViewDelegate to receive tag pressed event and used `isSelected` property. For unselected tag i set as orange color, while selected tag as white color. Each time user click unselected tag, the tag will turn to white color (become selected). For the default, user can select multiple tags. What i want to achieve is, user only can select one tag (turn to white color) at once. It means, other tags will remain unselected (turn to orange color). Below is the code on what i had already did:

```
    func tagPressed(_ title: String, tagView: TagView, sender: TagListView) {
   // print("Tag pressed: \(title), \(sender)")

    if tagView.isSelected == false {
        tagView.isSelected = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is more than solution this  fast and easy one  without update  original TagListView  classes to support one selection

```
       // MARK: TagListViewDelegate
            func tagPressed(_ title: String, tagView: TagView, sender: TagListView) 
      {
                print("Tag pressed: \(title), \(sender)")

                // loop over all tags and set selected to false

                 sender.tagViews.forEach {$0.isSelected = false}

                tagView.isSelected = !tagView.isSelected
     }
```

Comment: Very nice. It helped me. Thanks :)